# Not accepting same usernames in mysql database in php code

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote a code in php. In a form I don't want accepting usernames that exist in username column in a table in mysql. But it doesn't work and now I have same usernames in table. What should I do? this is the code:

```
 $sql="select * from $tbl_name where username=$username";
 $result=  mysql_query($db_link, $sql);
 $success=FALSE;
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0 ){
        $sql="insert into $tbl_name(username,password) values('$username','$pwd1')";
        mysql_query($sql, $db_link);
        $success=TRUE;
    }
```

The table name is stored in $tbl_name. The connection to the database is stored in $db_link.

Comment: pretty sure you could have asked better. try using mysql_num_rows() and see if its more than 0. but you should save the result first

Comment: shouldn't be like this? `$sql="select * from $tbl_name where username='$username'";` ... quote the `$username` in single quote!

Comment: `ALTER TABLE \`foo\` ADD UNIQUE INDEX \`username\` (\`username\`);`

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql='select COUNT(*) AS cnt from'.$tbl_name.'where username=.'$username;
 $result=  mysql_query($db_link, $sql);
 $res = mysql_fetch_array($result);
 $success=$res['cnt'];
    if($success == 0 ){
       // Do your insert here

    }
```